# What are the differences between nosmep and noexec=off

Tags: linux-kernel, x86

I am wondering the difference between this 2 arguments in linux's kernel command line:

- noexec=off
- nosmep

In both cases it denies kernel to execute code which is in userland memory.
But i cannot see any differences between them.

The error message in dmesg is different but the behaviour seems to be the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `noexec` parameter controls whether kernel can use the XD flag (also called the NX flag) of the paging structures to mark pages that are not supposed to be executable as such. The `nosmep` parameter, on the other hand, specifies whether SMEP is enabled. Note that `nosmep` only has an effect when both the kernel version and the processor support SMEP (See: [How can i enable/disable kernel kaslr, smep and smap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615925/how-can-i-enable-disable-kernel-kaslr-smep-and-smap)). In addition, XD only has an effect when the kernel is running in 64-bit or using 36-bit paging and `IA32_EFER.NXE` is set to 1.

The XD and SMEP flags determine whether the instruction at a given memory location can be fetched. SMEP overrides XD, which means that if SMEP is set, [supervisor-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55515674/4230618) code is not allowed to fetch instructions (for execution) from a User page irrespective of XD flag. Otherwise if SMEP is not supported or disabled, instruction fetch is not allowed in the following cases:

- Supervisor-mode code attempts to fetch instructions from a User or Supervisor page with a translation whose XD flag is 1 in at least one of the paging structures.
- User-mode code attempts to fetch instructions from a User page with a translation whose XD flag is 1 in at least one of the paging structures.
- User-mode code attempts to fetch instructions from a Supervisor page.

In any of these cases, a page fault Exception (#PF) occurs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here what i have tried: I wrote a c program which contains a function. I pass this function address to a kernel module which call it. SMEP and SMAP are disabled. What i do not understand is i need to set noexec=off in the kernel command line to make it work. How do you explain that ?

Comment: If you put these details in your question (including the code), we may be able to answer that question. Is this a custom kernel module you’ve written?